# generate servier-side highchart.js chart as image?

Tags: highcharts

I already know what chart save as image in client-side(web)
and I know save as image in server-side(phantom.js)

but the chart has a scroll and 
I want to save full screen(end scrolling) as one image file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8YYP.png)

How can I do that?
thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional chart options using [exporting.chartOptions](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions) property. Check demo I posted you below with xAxis scroll enabled and additional options to export where the scroll is disabled on chart load event.

**Code - exporting.chartOptions :**

```
  exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        events: {
          load: function() {
            var chart = this,
                max = chart.xAxis[0].dataMax;

            this.update({
              xAxis: {
                max: max,
                scrollbar: {
                  enabled: false
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/r1p47ekj/

Comment: Thanx for your answer!
but I said mean by that is not remove scrollbar.
I want to save as one image from start scroll to end scrolling

Comment: The example should have export the whole chart (from start to end scroll). I changed it a bit, could you check the example from the answer once again? Here is the same example: https://jsfiddle.net/r1p47ekj/